# Erro ao executar npx create-react-app, npm install e npm -v

Tags: node.js, react, windows, visual-studio-code, npm

Estou tentando criar um projeto React e até o momento não obtive sucesso no vscode em meu Windows 11. Segue o erro do código ao realizar npm install:

```
C:\Users\Caju\Documents\FIAP\GLOBAL SOLUTION 2\GlobalSolution2.0\FRONT-END> npm install
Falha na execução do programa 'npm.cmd': O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificadoNo linha:1 caractere:1
+ npm install
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~.
No linha:1 caractere:1
+ npm install
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Já inseri nas variáveis de sistema o path do nodejs e o diretório do npm, contudo, nada funcionando até o momento. Poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score -2):

Olá,

Isso pode acontecer se o Node.js e o npm não estiverem devidamente instalados ou se o caminho de instalação não estiver configurado corretamente nas variáveis de ambiente do sistema.

Aqui estão algumas soluções possíveis:

`1` Verifique se o Node.js e o npm estão instalados corretamente no seu sistema. Você pode fazer isso executando o comando `node -v` e `npm -v` no prompt de comando para verificar se eles são reconhecidos.

`2` Se você não tiver o Node.js e o npm instalados, baixe e instale a versão mais recente do Node.js a partir do site oficial (https://nodejs.org). Isso geralmente configura corretamente o caminho de instalação do npm.

`3` Verifique se o caminho de instalação do npm está configurado corretamente nas variáveis de ambiente do sistema. Para fazer isso, siga as etapas abaixo:

a) Abra o Painel de Controle do Windows.

b) Vá para Sistema e Segurança > Sistema.

c) Clique em "Configurações avançadas do sistema" no painel esquerdo.

d) Na janela "Propriedades do sistema", clique no botão "Variáveis de Ambiente".

e) Na seção "Variáveis do Sistema", localize a variável "Path" e clique em "Editar".

f) Verifique se o caminho para o diretório de instalação do npm (geralmente, C:\Program Files\nodejs) está listado. Se não estiver, adicione-o separado por ponto e vírgula.

g) Clique em OK em todas as janelas para salvar as alterações.

`4` Após verificar e configurar o Node.js e o npm corretamente, abra um novo prompt de comando ou reinicie o VSCode para que as alterações nas variáveis de ambiente tenham efeito.

`5` Tente executar o comando `npm install` novamente no diretório do seu projeto React para verificar se o problema foi resolvido.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Meu bom Deus... o cara dá uma resposta completa, as pessoas dão downvote. O cara faz uma pergunta pertinente, que eu tenho o mesmo problema, e as pessoas dão downvote. Por isso eu só uso o S.E. em inglês. Brasileiro só tem hater. Em vez de se preocupar em ajudar.... "Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais" .. fala sério.